# XML to CSV using XSL transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, csv

I have a XML data and I need to convert the same to CSV using xsl transformation. But the problem is, the XML rootnodes (refer to A, B, C nodes) varies. Please see below:

```
XML data
--------
<Sheets>
<A>
<Data>
<Row>
<value1>2</value1>
<value2>4</value2>
</Row>
<Row>
<value1>5</value1>
<value2>6</value2>
</Row>   
</Data>
</A>
<B>
<Data>
<Row>
<value1>12</value1>
<value2>13</value2>
</Row>
<Row>
<value1>14</value1>
<value2>15</value2>
</Row>
</Data>
</B>
<C>
<Data>
<Row>
<value1>1</value1>
<value2>1</value2>
</Row>
<Row>
<value1>2</value1>
<value2>2</value2>
</Row>
</Data>
</C>
</Sheets>
```

```
    CSV output should like this:
    ----------------------------
    A, 2, 4
    A, 5, 6
    B, 12, 13
    B, 14, 15
    C, 1, 1
    C, 2, 2
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example? Like, do you want to have files A.csv, B.csv and C.csv with the data as given here?

Comment: That would make A.csv e.g.:
2,4\n5,6 (sorry, no newlines here)

Comment: No. I need a single .csv file with the values like I mentioned in my question. I updated my question to show the CSV output now. Please  refer the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="/Sheets">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:variable name="dataSet" select="name()" />
            <xsl:for-each select="Data/Row">
                <xsl:value-of select="$dataSet" />
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. This works perfectly. But one thing I noticed is some of my text data (for example 0123 is shown as 123) is showing as integer value (I mean 0 get truncated in my text value). How to avoid that?

Comment: Still same issue. Also, for your information, I am writing the output to an Excel file. Is this issue because of that?

Comment: It seems to be fine when I open the file in notepad. Thank you so much.

Comment: Any idea why I am getting tab space in all my csv output rows? I tried <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />, normalize-space(.) & etc... but nothing works. There may be any issue in my xml data? Please help me.

Comment: I don't understand. Please elaborate.

Comment: I am getting some leading space in my output for all rows.

Comment: all rows or all rows except the first?

Answer (score 1):

This should output the text you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/Sheets">
<!-- This will match the letters -->
<xsl:for-each select="*">
<xsl:for-each select="*/descendant::Row">
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
<!-- Name of grand parent (two levels up) which is the letter -->
<xsl:value-of select="local-name(../..)"/><xsl:for-each select="*">, <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works but I got the output in Vertical manner. But it works without any issue. Thanks for your response.